# Regular expression to check number system

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on an application that takes numbers and converts them to the locale format. In order to do so I must first identify which locale the entered number belongs to format it accordingly.

Therefore, can anybody please provide Regex to match which number system the given number belongs too?

Example:

**Regex for number system 1:**

- 1 // should match
- 10 // should match
- 1000 //should match
- 1000.00 //should match
- 1,000.00 //should match

And so on..

**Regex for number system 2:**

- 1 // should match
- 10 // should match
- 1000 // should match
- 1.000 // should match
- 1.000,00 // should match

And so on..

**Regex for number system 3:**

- 1 // should match
- 10 // should match
- 1000 // should match
- 1 000 // should match
- 1 000.00 // should match.

And so on..

So far I have written this: `/^\d*[,]?\d*\.?\d+$/` But this doesn't work if there are more than one thousand separators. Example: 10,00,000.00

I basically need three regex to check which of the 3 widely used number system the entered number belongs to.

Comment: And what shoud not match?

Comment: If one number system is true, the other two must be false. :)

Comment: `1` matches in every system so all will be `true`

Comment: @Konrad that is alright

Comment: What did you do so far? What specific difficulty did you encounter?

Comment: @PiotrSiupa I have written this: /^\d*[,]?\d*\.?\d+$/ this doesn't work if there are more than one thousand separators. Example: 10,00,000.00

Answer (score 1):

```js
const commaDot = /^(?:\d{0,3}(?:,\d{3})|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?$/
const dotComma = /^(?:\d{0,3}(?:\.\d{3})|\d+)(?:,\d+)?$/
const spaceDot = /^(?:\d{0,3}(?: \d{3})|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?$/

const cases = [
  '1',
  '10',
  '1000',
  '1000.00',
  '1,000.00',

  '1',
  '10',
  '1000',
  '1000,00',
  '1.000,00',

  '1',
  '10',
  '1000',
  '1000.00',
  '1 000.00',
]

for (const cas of cases) {
  console.log(
    cas,
    'matches:',
    cas.match(commaDot) ? '1' : '',
    cas.match(dotComma) ? '2' : '',
    cas.match(spaceDot) ? '3' : ''
  )
}
```

Comment: 1000 shouldn't match 3 because in the third number system, there is a space for thousand separators, example: 1 000

Comment: This is an example from your question